# How to add a new record fto History tab in Glimpse

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, glimpse

I have Asp.Net SOAP Web Service (classic asmx web services) called `myservice` with one method `test()`. I added Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com/), enabled it and it adds records to the History tab every time where I reload url like `http://localhost/myservice.asmx` (list of available method is displayed). There is a client (another web site) which calls `myservice.test()` method. Unfortunately, Glimpse does not catch SOAP requests and does not add any records/urls to the History tab when that method is called. There is `Global.asax.cs` in the web service project. `Global.asax.cs` has method `Application_BeginRequest()` which is fired by ASP.Net framework automatically before calling `Test()` method.

I want to use Glimpse API to add a new record to the History tab from `Application_BeginRequest()` and then log some information into the Trace tab using, for example, `Trace.Write()` method. What classes and methods of Glimpse API I should call to add a new record to the History table? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of experimenting which included 1) continue googling to find anything similar
2) downloading and investigating work of several extensions for Glimpse
3) finding a way how to connect the source code to compile it with my test project to debug the source code of the Glimpse
4) scanning a lot of code of the Glimpse
5) making modification in the source code to ignore requests which Glimpse receives to get history + stopping and starting debugging the Glimpse many times , etc. I eventually found how to force the Glimpse to add records to the History. All you need is just add the following `<runtimePolicies>` tag to web.config of a project where I have web service:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
<runtimePolicies>
    <contentTypes>
        <add contentType="text/xml; charset=utf-8" runtimePolicy="On" />
    </contentTypes>
    <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy, Glimpse.Core" />
    </ignoredTypes>
</runtimePolicies>
```